# How to check if nested objects have children or not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, nested

I'm new to Javascript/React so I'm not sure how to implement this into my recursive function. I have a nested menu of json objects set up, and want to add little arrows indicating if there is another level to click to or not. Since my menu is made up of heavily nested json objects, I used recursion to go through all the objects and render them as a menu. I will include screenshots to visually explain what I'm trying to do as well.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to check if that layer of objects has children, and if so add an arrow (or anything) to indicate this?

Here is my code:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    categories: [],
    objectKeys: null,
    tempKeys: []
  };

  makeMenuLayer = layer => {
    const { objectKeys } = this.state;
    const layerKeys = Object.entries(layer).map(([key, value], index) => {
      return (
        <ul key={key}>
          <div onClick={() => this.handleShowMore(key)}>{key}</div>
          {objectKeys[key] && this.makeMenuLayer(value)}
        </ul>
      );
    });
    return <div>{layerKeys}</div>;
  };

  handleShowMore = key => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      objectKeys: {
        ...prevState.objectKeys,
        [key]: !this.state.objectKeys[key]
      }
    }));
  };

  initializeTempKeys = layer => {
    Object.entries(layer).map(([key, value]) => {
      const newTempKeys = this.state.tempKeys;
      newTempKeys.push(key);
      this.setState({ tempKeys: newTempKeys });
      this.initializeTempKeys(value);
    });
  };

  initializeObjectKeys = () => {
    const { tempKeys } = this.state;
    let tempObject = {};
    tempKeys.forEach(tempKey => {
      tempObject[tempKey] = true;
    });

    this.setState({ objectKeys: tempObject });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories").then(response => {
      this.setState({ categories: response.data });
    });
    const { categories } = this.state;
    this.initializeTempKeys(categories);
    this.initializeObjectKeys();
    this.setState({ categories });
  }

  render() {
    const { categories } = this.state;
    return <div>{this.makeMenuLayer(categories)}</div>;
  }
}
```

Here is how it currently looks, and I'd like it so any element that has more elements within it have an arrow or something to show there is more data nested (so for this, Apparel, Accessory, Clothing, etc would have arrows):

[image]

Here's an example of the type of thing I'm going for:

[image]

Comment: just type check for object type like this `typeof value=='object' && this.initializeTempKeys(value);`

Comment: Technical note: there is no such thing as a "JSON object" in this sense. There's JSON, which is a string representation of a Javascript object, and there are objects in Javascript. And then of courses there is the one "JSON object", being quite literally ["the `JSON` object"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) which lets you do things like `JSON.parse(...)` and `JSON.stringify(...)`, but that's not the one you're talking about here. It's worth editing your question to not talk about json, unless you're literally working with json strings.

Comment: You can check with the `typeof` whether key is object or not.`Ex` const obj = { "apparel": { "Accessory" : [ "Nectie", "umbrella" ]}}. console.log(typeof obj.apparel == 'object');. If it's a object call your recursive function.